# Concurrency issues in android sqlitehelper

Tags: android, sqlite, android-asynctask

i'm developing an app that uses sqlite database in android, and recently i'm having frequent crashes that i think are related with concurrent database access, altough the db exception is does not mention it..

here is the error:

```
09-15 15:25:45.672     195-1476/system_process V/ActivityManager﹕ Record #1 ActivityRecord{a52ecf58 u0 com.pauloslf.efatura/.MenuInicial}: app=ProcessRecord{a5317d60 0:com.pauloslf.efatura/u0a10049}
09-15 15:25:45.672     195-1476/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ Removing activity ActivityRecord{a52ecf58 u0 com.pauloslf.efatura/.MenuInicial} from stack at 1: haveState=false stateNotNeeded=false finishing=true state=PAUSING
        java.lang.RuntimeException: here
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.removeHistoryRecordsForAppLocked(ActivityStack.java:4249)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleAppDiedLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:3015)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.appDiedLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:3085)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService$AppDeathRecipient.binderDied(ActivityManagerService.java:897)
        at android.os.BinderProxy.sendDeathNotice(Binder.java:470)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
09-15 15:25:45.672      195-490/system_process W/InputDispatcher﹕ channel 'a5239e68 com.pauloslf.efatura/com.pauloslf.efatura.MenuInicial (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
09-15 15:25:45.672      195-490/system_process E/InputDispatcher﹕ channel 'a5239e68 com.pauloslf.efatura/com.pauloslf.efatura.MenuInicial (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
09-15 15:25:45.672     195-1476/system_process V/ActivityManager﹕ No result destination from ActivityRecord{a52ecf58 u0 com.pauloslf.efatura/.MenuInicial}
09-15 15:25:45.676      119-119/? D/Zygote﹕ Process 3287 terminated by signal (11)
09-15 15:25:45.684     195-1915/system_process W/InputDispatcher﹕ Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel 'a5239e68 com.pauloslf.efatura/com.pauloslf.efatura.MenuInicial (server)'
```

I'm accessing the db class using a singleton:

```
 private static FacturasDB faturasdb = null;

    public static FacturasDB getInstance(Context context) {
        if (faturasdb == null) {
            faturasdb = new FacturasDB(context);
        }
        return faturasdb;
    }
```

The most easy way for me to reproduce the issue is when the asynctask started on the main activity (does db access on the background) is running and i navigate to another activity that also uses the db..

Any idea why this issue happens ?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: How do you synchronize accesses to the database?

Comment: Using the singleton there is only 1 instance.. and as far as i know the sqlitehelper is threadsafe